# How do I quit / exit / stop Xcode Server?

Tags: process, exit

I have this little hammer up next to volume, power, time, etc.  How do I make it go away?  The options menu is grayed-out.  No menu item to shut it down that I can find.

Comment: How the heck did this thing start to begin with? I don't recall having started up XCode Server. And why the heck doesn't it have a quit option?? >:C

Comment: @user124384: For me, I clicked on it somewhere in XCode. It asked me if I wanted to start the XCode Server. I said no. Here I am....

Answer (score 30):

Open the `Activity Monitor` app and kill `Xcode Server Builder` app from the list.

[image: Activity Monitor Screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

Just had this problem, I ran the following command in the terminal to fixed it

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}')
```

which kills all processes with Xcode in their name.

Commmand from: https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/how-to-kill-xcode-from-the-command-line/

Comment: I don't want to kill the IDE though.

Answer (score 2):

i was killing the process but it was restarting automatically after it, so I opened xcode > preferences > Server and Bots and switched to off:

[image: server and bots preferences]

Comment: Still keeps restarting even after I turn it off in Xcode...

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Activity Monitor** app, and then select Quit to kill the process

In case that the XCode Server Builder" is the restarting each time that you try to kill it, it's probably because you have the **xcscontrol** process

To kill this process, you can just shutdown the daemon with this code:

`sudo /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/CurrentXcodeSymlink/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcscontrol  --shutdown`

For future versions, and in case that the path change, you can check the right path with this line in terminal:

```
ps aux | grep xcscontrol
```

Comment: I found that I needed to use a different subcommand: `sudo xcscontrol --reset`.

According to the help text "--reset Resets Xcode Server, removing all service data and stopping all services".

After resetting, the hammer was still in my menu bar, but it went away and stayed away after I killed the Xcode Server Builder process in activity monitor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Activity Monitor app to visualize all your running processes, the select the "Xcode Server" one, and click on the cross icon on the top left. That will kill the process.